# Appium - runAppInBackground throws WebDriverException

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm using Appium to automate the tests of an Android app. Recently I stuck on an error while trying to test the behavior of the app when it gets pushed to background and relaunched again. I was lucky, that I found the method `appiumDriver.runAppInBackground(Duration duration)`.

...But when I'm executing `appiumDriver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(1));` I receive an exception.

I run the tests on an android Emulator (PIXEL_API_25) and I use Appium 1.7.2 with java_client 5.0.4, but in future, they should also run on iOS.

The appiumDriver variable is static (not sure if this could make a difference...).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile I've found a solution which works for me.

With updating Appium from 1.7.2 to 1.8.1 the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty clear what went wrong in stacktrace:

`Original error: 'Command ''C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe' -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n de.abc.myApp/.BookingOverviewActivity' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=de.abc.myApp/.BookingOverviewActivity } from null (pid=7759, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10224`

Appium failed to launch your app back from background because of *permission restriction*. Try with 5 seconds and different device.

If still reproduced: to fix it, you need to update you application source code with `android:exported="true"` in manifest file for `BookingOverviewActivity` activity.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! 5 seconds and a different device didn't work for me. And at the moment I'm not able to change the app source code, I'll hope I can try this later.